# Don't Understand Error During gSOAP Serialization

Tags: c#, c++, xml, xml-serialization, gsoap

Working with gSoap 2.7.17 on Windows, C# and managed C++.

I have (gSOAP) classes describing an array of files:

```
class ns__ContainerFile
{
public:
    xsd__long           fileId;
    xsd__string         fileName;
};

class ContainerFileArray
{
public:
    ns__ContainerFile         *__ptr;
    int                       __size;
};

class ns__Container
{
public:
    xsd__long           containerId     0:1 = 0;
    xsd__string         name            0:1 = "";
    xsd__string         description     0:1 = "";
    ContainerFileArray* files           0:1 = NULL;
};
```

In managed c++, I allocate my return array:

```
ContainerFileArray gSoapArray;
gSoapArray.__size = managedArray->Length;
gSoapArray.__ptr = (ns__ContainerFile*) soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(ns__ContainerFile) * gSoapArray.__size);
```

The code above is part of a method named ConvertArray, which is called thus:

```
ns__Container unManaged;
*unManaged.files = ConvertArray(soap, managed->files->ToArray());
```

Problem is, while the ConvertArray appears to run properly (I can see the data elements seemingly properly filled in within the malloc'ed memory), I'm getting access violations during the serialization step when we are wrapping up the web service request (ie: our C++ code has issued the SOAP_OK return value and the logic has returned to the auto-generated gSOAP code).

This whole process works just fine when dealing with arrays of simple types - ints, longs, etc but blows up with more complex types - classes and the like.

If, in the ConvertArray method, I substitute on line 3:

```
gSoapArray.__ptr = soap_new_ns__ContainerFile(soap, gSoapArray.__size);
```

to allocate the memory, it works fine.

So, I'm not sure I understand why.  In the first case, I'm using soap_malloc to allocate a block of memory that is the size of the ContainerFile class times however many elements are in the managed array.  In the second case, it boils down to using soap_new to do the same thing.  If the allocated memory is all managed by gsoap and is otherwise the same (as far as I can tell), why should the soap_malloc'ed version fail during serialization?

Using Visual Studio, I can see that it fails in the following generated code:

```
void ContainerFileArray::soap_serialize(struct soap *soap) const
{
    if (this->__ptr && !soap_array_reference(soap, this, (struct soap_array*)&this->__ptr, 1, SOAP_TYPE_ContainerFileArray))
        for (int i = 0; i < this->__size; i++)
        {    soap_embedded(soap, this->__ptr + i, SOAP_TYPE_IDCXDService__ContainerFile);
            this->__ptr[i].soap_serialize(soap);
        }
}
```

The indicator is on the highlighted line, but I suspect it failed in the soap_embedded call.  I should also note that it fails on the first element in the malloc'd block (ie: when i == 0).

Answer (score 0):

You should always use 'new' instead of 'malloc' in C++, as in:

```
gSoapArray.__ptr = soap_new_ ns__ContainerFile(soap, gSoapArray.__size);
```

Or even better, use STL std::vector in the gSOAP header file as follows:

```
#import "stlvector.h"
class ns__Container
{
public:
    xsd__long           containerId     0:1 = 0;
    xsd__string         name            0:1 = "";
    xsd__string         description     0:1 = "";
    std::vector<ns__ContainerFile> files           0:1 = NULL;
};
```

Basically, malloc is not safe in C++ because the VMT of the instance is not initialized so a dynamic method invocation leads to a crash.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain your last comment in simpler terms, please?